# Moving site to new server - admin area not working

Tags: migration

I am trying to move a Craft site to a new server but am having difficulties.

I have backed up the whole site and database an replicated it on a new server.

3 pages work fine, one page only loads the header, and the admin page lets me login but the dashboard is blank but there are no console errors in chrome.

I have changed my host files on my mac to point the domain to the new server so I'm not sure if this might cause issues?

Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: What's in your apache (or nginx) error log?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with debugging the control panel. If you enable devMode, and load the dashboard, you might see any error message that display on the screen that would give you a clue what's going on.

If it's not there, then some error message is probably being logged in your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files that would help.  Open that files and do a search for `[error]` and look for any suspicious messages.